# React: 'selected' attribute not working with multiple <select> elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have a React component that has multiple `<select>` (not react-select) elements. Only one `<select>` is rendered based on one of the props:

```
class SelectGroup extends Component {

...

  render () {

    let activeSelect

    switch (this.props.foo) {
      case 'select1':
        activeSelect = <select id="select1">
          <option value="1a" selected>1 A</option>
          <option value="1b">1 B</option>
          <option value="1c">1 C</option>
        </select>
        break
      case 'select2':
        activeSelect = <select id="select2">
          <option value="2a" selected>2 A</option>
          <option value="2b">2 B</option>
          <option value="2c">2 C</option>
        </select>
        break
      ...
    }

    return activeSelect
  }
...
}
```

(For our purposes, assume that `SelectGroup` is nested inside another component, which changes the prop `foo` when a button is clicked.)

What I want is for the first option for each `<select>` to be selected by default whenever we change which `<select>` is being rendered (whenever the prop `foo` is changed). As you can see, I gave the first option of each `<select>` the `selected` attribute which, according to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected), should make it the default option. However, that's not the behavior I'm seeing. Here's what happens:

1. `select1` is being displayed. I choose option `1b` from the dropdown.
2. I click the button to switch to `select2`.
3. I expect for `2a` to be selected because it has the `selected` attribute. However, `2b` is selected instead.
4. I select `2c` from the dropdown.
5. I click the button to switch back to `select1`.
6. I expect for `1a` to be selected. However, `1c` is selected instead.

It seems to be completely ignoring the `selected` attribute and instead it looks like it's selecting the option from the list that corresponds to whichever option was selected before changing which `<select>` is rendered.

Oddly, if I remove the `selected` attribute from all `<select>` elements except `select1`, then `select1` will behave as expected: when I switch to `select1`, it will always display option `1a` regardless of what was selected before, but the option displayed by `select2` will continue to depend on whatever was chosen before switching to it. So it's as if `selected` only works if it is only used once, but I don't understand why that is, since it is only being applied to one option per `<select>`.

How can I get the first option to be selected whenever I switch between which `<select>` is being rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a unique `key` to each select:

```
    switch (this.props.foo) {
      case 'select1':
        activeSelect = <select key="select1" id="select1">
          <option value="1a" selected>1 A</option>
          <option value="1b">1 B</option>
          <option value="1c">1 C</option>
        </select>
        break
      case 'select2':
        activeSelect = <select key="select2" id="select2">
          <option value="2a" selected>2 A</option>
          <option value="2b">2 B</option>
          <option value="2c">2 C</option>
        </select>
        break
      ...
```

This will force a complete rerender of the select. What is happening is most likely when you switch from one to the other, react's VDOM kicks in and it modifies the existing select rather than replaces it. Due to (quite weird and archaic) DOM behaviors, the selected value of the old select is retained.

By using a unique `key` it will force React to completely rerender the whole node, throwing away any selected value state in memory in the process.

What you are doing is a bit weird btw -- there are almost certainly better ways but I don't know enough about your use case. You probably want to instead conditionally render them inline, which means in the internal representation of the component held by React, they are 2 separate nodes:

```
return <>
    {this.props.foo === "select1" && 
       <select id="select1">
          <option value="1a" selected>1 A</option>
          <option value="1b">1 B</option>
          <option value="1c">1 C</option>
        </select>
    }
    {this.props.foo === "select2" && 
       <select id="select1">
          <option value="1a" selected>1 A</option>
          <option value="1b">1 B</option>
          <option value="1c">1 C</option>
        </select>
    }

</>
```

You might think "how is this any different". Well, the inactive ones will render false (which renders nothing). But that it renders "false" means that node is represented separately as that value and not stuffed into one, which is why reacts vdom is thinking it's the exact same node.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I thought that each one having a unique `id` attribute would accomplish the same thing and that `key` was only used for keeping lists of components straight. I'll keep this in mind for future use.
As for the second code snippet, it does look like the first should be just as valid, but understanding what you said about how the DOM treats them, it makes sense why the second approach would be preferable. Good to know! Thanks again!