# react involuntarily submitting form when using ternary operator

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the "Show Submit" button, the `handleSubmit` function runs even though I haven't clicked on the "Send" button yet. Why is this?

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {

  const [showSubmit, setShowSubmit] = useState(false);   
  
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (showSubmit) {
      console.log("run");
    }
  };

  const handleShowSubmit = () => {
    setShowSubmit(true);
  }; 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {showSubmit ? (
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        ) : (
          <button type="button" onClick={handleShowSubmit}>
            Show Submit
          </button>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Replacing the ternary operator in the `return` statement with the code block below, with `&&` resolves the issue. could anyone explain the behavior?

```js
{showSubmit && (
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
)}
{!showSubmit && (
  <button type="button" onClick={handleShowSubmit}>
    Show Submit
  </button>
)}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say when you click the button called "show submit", `handleShowSubmit` runs. Thats exactly what the displayed code does in both blocks of code, simply because `handleShowSubmit` is the `onClick` handler of the "show submit" button. I think you meant `handleSubmit `?

Comment: yes, my bad thats what i ment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in your original question and when you said "the `handleShowSubmit` function runs even though I haven't clicked on the "Send" button yet" you actually meant `handleSubmit`.

What you have come across is actually a very rare edge case in React. When you use the ternary, you are rendering either type of button in a single expression, wrapped by `{}`. This enables React to apply its VDOM diffing algorithm when the `showSubmit` bool flips. React tries to save computation when it can, which means instead of completely removing and replacing one button with the other, it patches the original button with the changes needed to make it into the other button by modifying its HTML attributes using granular DOM calls.

99% of the time this is fine and you don't even need to know this is happening. However, a limited amount of HTML elements like form elements can hold some state that is retained when React does this. In this case, what is likely happening is that by the time the click event on the "Show Submit" button is executed, in the intervening time, react has modified that button to be the "submit" button and so it submits the form.

I answered a question previously which is actually a similar affect: [React: 'selected' attribute not working with multiple <select> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74482448/react-selected-attribute-not-working-with-multiple-select-elements/74482680#74482680).

In your second example, you have 2 unique expressions (two sets of `{...}`), and so react does not patch one button to the other when the state changes since it treats them as 2 unique values. When one button renders, the representation of the other button is "false". They are completely unique buttons and the DOM state that backs them is entirely separate. Whereas in the ternary, there is one representation for both, with React patching one button to the other.

If you'd rather use the ternary, you could force react to treat each button differently by setting a unique `key` on them:

```
       {showSubmit ? (
          <button key="send" type="submit">Send</button>
        ) : (
          <button key="show" type="button" onClick={handleShowSubmit}>
            Show Submit
          </button>
        )}
```